# Luigi flexible pipeline and passing parameters all the way through

Tags: python, pipeline, luigi

I've recently implemented a luigi pipeline to handle the processing for one of our bioinformatics pipelines. However, there's something fundamental about how to setup these tasks that I'm not grasping.

Let's say I've got a chain of three tasks that I'd like to be able to run with multiple workers. For example, the dependency graph for three workers might look like:

/ taskC -> taskB -> taskA 
- taskC -> taskB -> taskA 
\ taskC -> taskB -> taskA

and I might write

```python
class entry(luigi.Task):

    in_dir = luigi.Parameter()

    def requires(self):
        for f in self.in_dir:
            yield taskC(pass_through=f)

    def run(self):
        some logic using self.input().path
        from each worker in the above yield

class taskA(luigi.Task):

    in_file_A = luigi.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('outA.txt')

    def run(self):
        some logic generating outA.txt

class taskB(luigi.Task):

    pass_through = luigi.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('outB.txt')

    def requires(self):
        return taskA(in_file_A=self.pass_through)

    def run(self):
        some logic using self.input().path [outA.txt] 
        and generating self.output().path [outB.txt]

class taskC(luigi.Task):

    pass_through = luigi.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('outC.txt')

    def requires(self):
        return taskB(pass_through=self.pass_through)

    def run(self):
        some logic using self.input().path [outB.txt] 
        and generating self.output().path [outC.txt]
```

If my code lives in `pipeline.py` I might launch this with:

```
luigi --module pipeline entry --workers 3 --in-dir some_dir_w_input_files/
```

The fact that I'm sending parameter `pass_through` all the way through to `taskA` doesn't feel like the right approach. Furthermore, if sometime in the future I already have the data generated (separately) by `taskA`, `taskB` isn't flexible enough to handle that situation. Perhaps I might write:

```python
class taskB(luigi.Task):

    in_file_B = luigi.Parameter() # if we already have the output of taskA
    pass_through = luigi.Parameter() # if we require taskA

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('outB.txt')

    def requires(self):
        if self.pass_through:
            return taskA(in_file_A=self.pass_through)

    def run(self):
        if self.input().path:
           logic_input = self.input().path
        else:
           logic_input = self.in_file_B

        some logic using 'logic_input'
        and generating self.output().path [outB.txt]
```

I'd like to know if this is the 'proper' design pattern for Luigi or if I'm completely off base.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is largely an artifact of the abstract tasks you have here, in the real world, you probably need to know at each where you are reading from / writing to. See for example:

```
class DecompressTask(luigi.Task):
    dirname = luigi.Parameter()
    filename = luigi.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(os.path.join(self.dirname , self.filename + ".txt"))

    def run(self):
        decompress(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename + ".gz"),
                   os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename + ".txt"))


class TranslateTask(luigi.Task):
    dirname = luigi.Parameter()
    filename = luigi.Parameter()

    def requires(self):
        return DecompressTask(dirname=self.dirname, filename=self.filename)

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(os.path.join(self.dirname + self.filename + ".translated"))

    def run(self):
        translate(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename + ".txt"),
                  os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename + ".translated"))


class ProcessDirectory(luigi.WrapperTask):
    dirname = luigi.Parameter()

    def requires(self):
        tasks = []
        for file_name in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            if file_name.endswith("gz"):
                prefix = file_name.split(".")[0]
                tasks.append(TranslateTask(filename=prefix, dirname=self.dirname))
        return tasks
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers my question completely. The parameters for `taskA` are defined only after the dependency tree has been generated - each worker sets the input file (not dir) for `taskA`. In my example, I'd need a way of setting --taskA-in-file-A from within the `entry` task (similarly to how I'm passing that file name through in the `passthrough` parameter)

Comment: Yeah, your example is really messed up, because the output for all of your TaskB and TaskC is single static file name, once one runs, that task will be considered done forever.