# configure pipeline with custom config in luigi

Tags: python, config, luigi

Here is a nice partial answer to my problem:
[Luigi flexible pipeline and passing parameters all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612459/)

I have the same pipeline, but I want to configure it with custom config (**not** luigi.cfg)

```
/ taskC -> taskB -> taskA 
- taskC -> taskB -> taskA 
\ taskC -> taskB -> taskA
```

Config file looks like:

```
[servername]
username=name
password=password

[servername2]
username=name2
password=password2

[servername3]
username=name3
password=password3
```

So I started like this:

```
class configure(luigi.WrapperTask):
    configname = luigi.Parameter()
        def run(self):
            with self.input().open('r') as file ini:
                for i in sections:
                    # read section from ini 

        def requires(self):
            tasks = []
            # here I also need for-loop
            return tasks
```

Please help to implement: 
FOR-LOOP
1. read ini file
2. read next section 
3. do workflow
4. goto 1
/FOR-LOOP

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?